# Token expires to SPO list: how can I make this persist for data refreshes?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have a data connection in my Tabular model that is 2019/1500 compatibility level.

I have the model in VS 2019, and am refreshing data from an SPO list.

The issue is that when I go to refresh the token expires and I have to manually go to the data source connection credentials and refresh them.

How can I set this up so I don't have to use a token that expires?

Currently my connection details are listed as:

```
{
  "protocol": "sharepoint-list",
  "address": {
    "url": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/p/SomePage"
  },
  "authentication": null,
  "query": null
}
```

and my security credentials:

```
{"AuthenticationKind":"OAuth2","Expires":"Mon, 13 Jul 2020 17:11:44 GMT","RefreshToken":"********","ProviderType":"SharePointAAD"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was struggling with the same problem and found : [Using Sharepoint Lists in SSAS](https://mytwospence.spencerswindell.com/2019/04/using-sharepoint-lists-in-ssas.html)
Seems SSAS does not refresh the OAuth2 tokens. So the article has a Powershell script to refresh these.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)